# How to read the saml response that comes to the "../adfs/ls/"?

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I am new to the SSO and SAML . We have to set up Single sign on the our customer site using ADFS 2.0  and we did that successfully and when we try to access `../adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx` and it redirects to the customer site and if we enter the user name and password and it brings back to the `idpinitiatedsignon.aspx` page with you are signed in label. When i check the http transactions using  SAML Tracer firefox plug in , i can see the `<samlp:Response>` is coming to `our_site_name/adfs/ls/` and when i tried to access `Request["SAMLResponse"]` in `idpinitiatedsignon.aspx`page , it shows as nothing.

1. how do i read the `samlp:response`that comes to my server and not
       to particular page ?

   2. I can see in the SAML Tracer that i'm getting `<EncryptedAssertion>`.How can i read the assertion values?

Comment: What is the problem? Is there anything in the ADFS event log?

Comment: @nzpcmad : I'm asking how to read the saml response in asp.net ?

Comment: have u seen <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359232/how-can-i-configure-adfs-on-my-windows-server-machine-system/37831734#37831734>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering from SAML and not from ADFS. Regarding question 2, i would expect that you would have received a block of XML called SAML Metadata that describes your customer's IDP. In that metadata, i would expect that you would receive your customer's public key ([2.4.1.1 Element KeyDescriptor](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35391/sstc-saml-metadata-errata-2.0-wd-04-diff.pdf)). I don't think it's possible to decrypt in SAML Tracer unless there is a way to install the encryption cert in the tool.  My team has used the XmlSecTool, available from https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/XmlSecTool,  for verifying an XML signature pulled out of SAML tracer, but i don't know if anyone has a way to decrypt at the browser. Forgive me if you are asking more specifically at the ASDF level.

Comment: @ judielaine : thanks for the idea and  if you have any idea /solution for my first question ? how to read the saml response that is coming to my server ?

Comment: 1. It is really hard to get at the SAML token in ADFS itself. Decoding is done in an HttpHandler. Only with an Http Module you could intercept it. Is it worth the effort? What do you want?   2. You would have to get the private key of the Decryption certificate out of the CAPI store (if it is not in and HSM :-). Non-trivial (non-exportable) for default self-signed, but doable by importing one into ADFS.

Comment: @Dhanda My regrets, i've never used ADFS so i'm not able to help with that aspect.

Comment: @paullem : We are trying to implement SSO with our customer site.we are the SP and Idp is customer side.so once i run my adfs idpinitiatedsignon.aspx page , It successfully redirect to customer site and once we enter username and password it successfully comes back to idpinitiatedsignon.aspx and says you are signed in. So next is to capture samlp:response so that i can read assertions but I don't know how to read that ? Is there any way to get the saml response in c# ?

Comment: You did not answer my question why you want this. Normal flow is that your application redirects to ADFS (using ws-fed). Then ADFS redirects to the IdP (using saml2 protocol). The IdP returns the SAML token through a Post. Then ADFS resigns and posts to your application. No need (better not) for IdP Initiated. My advice is to stick to the standard flow. I have already answered what to do if you do not stick to the standard flow.