# How can I configure ADFS on my windows server machine system?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs2.0

I want to configure ADFS to create single signon service and use the same for another web application. I am very new to this. Please suggest me how to do it or at least where to start. 
  Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can only install on Windows Server.

If you want ADFS 2.0 you need Server 2008 R2.

[Install](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-step-by-step-guides%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The latest (ADFS 3.0) is on Server 2012 r2.

**Update**

Is the application Java or .NET?

You need a SAML client side stack - refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

You then take the SAML client metadata and import into ADFS as a RP (SP) and take the ADFS metadata and import into your application as a CP (IDP).

Comment: yes i have configure adfs on server 2012 but now how can i communicate between my web app and adfs using saml 2.0. please help.

Comment: Thanks for all these point, i am unable to create SAML client metadata on my web site would you please suggest?

Comment: You could create it dynamically - e.g. https://syfuhs.net/2010/11/03/generating-federation-metadata-dynamically/ or look at identityserver

Answer (score 0):

few months ago i had asked this question, I forget to answer how I achieved this :

1. We have created a test site where we have used form-authentication technique to authenticate any user, It requires an authentication token to authorize any user on application.
2. So for creating this token we have to communicate with the Identity provider (IP) to get authenticated user details.
3. For communicating with the IP server we have used SAML protocol to send and receive requests and responses.
4. IP already provided us their end point details and certificate which is required to send and receive the SAML Packet.
5. We have also sent our End points, certificate and claim rules so that they can configure our test site with their ADFS server as a relying party.
6. As the result of all this we are able to redirect an anonymous access on our site to their ADFS server in the form of a SAML request.
7. They are also able to process it and sending us response with all details of user like name, username, email etc.
8. We have used third party .dll to generate and process the SAML request, the name is : ComponentSpace (http://www.componentspace.com/).